# Report number of subscribers in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions

Hope you can help.

I have my subscribers with an active consent transfered into a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud daily, and I would like to have the number of subscribers in that Data Extension exported daily (in a mail preferably) for statistic purposes.

I can't seem to find a report that can handle doing this, as they handle list and not data extensions.

Could anyone guide me in a direction of solving this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own email (report) including the information you need including the number of subscribers.

All you need to do is use the [RowCount()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm) ( or [DataExtensionRowCount()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dataextensionrowcount.htm) ) in AMPscript to print your count in the email.

Afterwords you'll set-up an automation running daily to send that email.

Comment: Thank you @ZakBen - quite an alternative solution but none the less it delivers what I need :) Now I'll look into what other data I could access this way